# Get an evenly distributed subset of combinations without repetition

Tags: python, statistics, combinations

I'm trying to get a subset of combinations such that every option is used the same amount of times, *or close to it*, from the total set of combinations without repetition. For example, I have 8 options (let's say A-H) and I need combinations of 4 letters where order doesn't matter. That would give me 70 possible combinations. I would like to take a subset of those combinations such that A appears as much as each other letter does, and A appears with B as much as C appears with D, etc. I know there are subsets where it is impossible to have each letter appear the same amount of times and appear with another letter the same amount of times so when I say "same amount of times" in this post, I mean the same amount or close to it.

If the options are written out in an organized list as is shown below, I couldn't just select the first N options because that would give A far more use than it would H. Also, A and B would appear together more than C and D. The main idea is to get as evenly distributed use of each letter combination as possible.

ABCD ABCE ABCF ABCG ABCH ABDE ABDF ABDG ABDH ABEF ABEG ABEH ABFG ABFH ABGH ACDE ACDF ACDG ACDH ACEF ACEG ACEH ACFG ACFH ACGH ADEF ADEG ADEH ADFG ADFH ADGH AEFG AEFH AEGH AFGH BCDE BCDF BCDG BCDH BCEF BCEG BCEH BCFG BCFH BCGH BDEF BDEG BDEH BDFG BDFH BDGH BEFG BEFH BEGH BFGH CDEF CDEG CDEH CDFG CDFH CDGH CEFG CEFH CEGH CFGH DEFG DEFH DEGH DFGH EFGH

I could take a random sample but being random, it doesn't exactly meet my requirements of taking a subset intentionally to get an even distribution. It could randomly choose a very uneven distribution.

Is there a tool or a mathematical formula to generate a list like I'm asking for? Building one in Python or some other coding language is an option if I had an idea of how to go about it.

**EDIT** - Think of it like ingredients. A-H are each unique ingredients such as flour, sugar, butter, etc. I'm creating recipes that use four of the available ingredients (not worrying about measurements, just what ingredients are used).

There are 70 possible combinations of the 8 ingredients (put in 8 objects and 4 sample size [here](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/combinations.php)). I want a list of a subset of those combinations, of a size I put into the formula. As an example, let's say I want 20 of the combinations. I want each ingredient to show up as much as the other ingredients, meaning among those combinations, maybe A (flour) is used 3 times, B (sugar) is used 3 times, C (butter) is used 3 times, etc.

I also want A (flour) and B (sugar) to be used together as many times as B (sugar) and C (butter) are used together in a combination.

Most subset sizes won't allow perfect distribution of items, but it should give a list that is as close to an even distribution as possible.

I have created a Python script that I think does what I want. I'm cleaning it up and testing it more, then I'll post it here.

To show an example of correct results, I found that a subset of size 14 will produce a perfect distribution:

```
ABCD  ADEG  BDGH
ABEH  ADFH  CDEH
ABFG  BCEG  CDFG
ACEF  BCFH  EFGH
ACGH  BDEF
```

You can see that in that subset, each letter is used 7 times, and each pairing (such as A and B) appear 3 times, and each triplet (such as A and B and C) appears once. This is the exact type of result I'm looking for. I hope that clarifies the problem for readers.

I'll post my python code soon.

Comment: When returning back to your `A-H` case, how do expect to request combinations (by any or by even search items)? Say, you're requesting `A` and `G`, should it give you the same number of unique 4-itemed combinations for `A` and `G` ? Can you request `A`, `B` and `H` at a time?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the probem. I edited the post to (hopefully) clarify better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the Python code to create a balanced subset from a list of options. I commented enough for it to explain itself. In a nutshell, it iterates through the possible combinations, scoring each option according to how well it keeps the resulting list balanced. The combinations with the best scores get included in the final list of selections.

```
import itertools
import random

allOptions = 'ABCDEFGH'
# allOptions can be a list of anything, such as:
# allOptions = ['Flour', 'Sugar', 'Eggs', 'Frosting', 'Butter', 'Chocolate', 'Berries', 'Milk']

# Subset sizes with perfect distributions: 14, 28, 70
subsetSize = 14

# The number of letters in the combos of final results (i.e. ABCD)
comboSize = 4

# 2D list of counts of each combo, indexed by # of characters, for example:
#  count[1] = ["A"=7, "B"=7, "C"=7...] number of times single characters appear
#  count[2] = ["AB"=3, "AC"=3, "AD"=3...] number of times pairs appear together
#  count[3] = ["ABC"=1, "ABD"=1, "ABE"=1...] number of times three letters appear together
selectionCount = [dict()] * comboSize

# Initialized to 1 since scores start at 0, indexes are # of characters like selectionCount
maxScoreTarget = [1] * comboSize

# Initialized to 0, will be used to keep list balanced 
overageScore = [0] * comboSize


# The primary function that will iterate over the list of combinations, selecting the options
#  that create a balanced subset.
def selectCombos():
    global overageScore
    global selectionCount

    # The final selection results
    selections = [] # list of objects [("a", "b", "c", "d"), ("e", "f", "g", "h")]
    
    # Initialize selectionCount to use for keeping track of singles, pairs, and trios usage
    selectionCount = makeCounts()
    
    # Create the list that will be pulled from as we identify the best combos
    comboOptions = list(itertools.combinations(allOptions, 4))

    # Shuffle the list of combos so it isn't always starting with ABCD
    # This helps with testing to see if the results are consistent
    random.shuffle(comboOptions)

    # Used to hold the current combo selection
    selection = ""
    
    # Each run through this loop will select another combo
    for subsetCount in range(1, subsetSize):
        # We have to start somewhere so the first in the list is the first to be selected
        if len(selections) == 0:
            selection = comboOptions[0]
            # Move the selection from the comboOptions list to the selections list. 
            selections.append(selection)
            comboOptions.remove(selection)
            # Update the count of each single letter, pair, and trio
            adjustCounts(selection)

        # A dict to hold scores of the combos, such as 'ABCD': 5. See scoring function.
        optionScores = dict()
        lowestScore = 999    # initialize to something that will be replaced.
        # Overage score 
        overageScore = [0] * comboSize

        # Calling a 4 letter combo a 'word'
        for word in comboOptions:
            # Make wordIndex from combo by turning ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D') into 'ABCD'.
            wordIndex = "".join(word)
            # Score the word
            optionScores[wordIndex] = scoreCandidate(word)
            # If score is less than lowestScore, replace lowest score and set selection
            if optionScores[wordIndex] < lowestScore or optionScores[wordIndex] == 0:
                lowestScore = optionScores[wordIndex]
                selection = word
        # We'll call the number of letters the category, i.e. 2 is 2 letter pairs.
        for category in range(1, comboSize):
            # If every combo caused a count to exceed the maxScore, it's time to increase the score
            if overageScore[category] >= len(comboOptions)-1:
                maxScoreTarget[category] += 1

        if selection:
            # Move our selection from the comboOptions list to the selections list
            selections.append(selection)
            comboOptions.remove(selection)
            # Update the count of each single letter, pair, and trio
            adjustCounts(selection)
        else:
            print("THERE WAS NO SELECTION")
    
    # Create a list of the joined combos so it's easy to read ('ABCD' instead of ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))
    easylist = []
    for word in selections:
        easylist.append(''.join(word))
    # Sort them so it's easier to compare
    easylist.sort()

    # Output the resulting selections
    print('SELECTIONS')
    for word in easylist:
        print(word)
    
    # Output the count of each single letter, pair, and trio
    for catSet in selectionCount:
        print('----')
        for value in catSet:
            print(value, catSet[value])


# Adjusts the count of each single letter, pair, and trio based on the selection we've identified
def adjustCounts(selection):
    global selectionCount
    # Get all the singles, pairs, and trios in the selection
    selectionCombos = getWordCombos(selection)
    for category in range(1, comboSize):
        for combo in selectionCombos[category]:
            comboIndex = "".join(combo)
            # Increment the count for the combo in the selection count dict
            selectionCount[category][comboIndex] += 1


# Scores a candidate combo, based on how it affects the count of single letters, pairs, and trios
def scoreCandidate(word):
    global overageScore
    global selectionCount
    # word = ["a","b","c","d"]
    wordScore = 0
    # Checking each category, which is how many letters again.
    for category in range(1, comboSize):
        isOverage = False
        # Get all the [category] letter combinations of this 4 letter combo
        for item in list(itertools.combinations(word, category)):
            index = "".join(item)
            # See if the option would increase the selectionCount to exceed the maxScoreTarget
            if selectionCount[category][index] + 1 > maxScoreTarget[category]:
                difference = selectionCount[category][index] + 1 - maxScoreTarget[category]
                # The more the candidate exceeds the maxScoreTarget, the worse it is.
                #  This gives preference to candidates that don't cause so much imbalance.
                match difference:
                    case 1:
                        wordScore += 1
                    case 2:
                        wordScore += 5
                    case 3:
                        wordScore += 20
                # Since increasing the selectionCount for this option exceeds the maxScoreTarget, set the flag
                isOverage = True

        # When there's an overage, add to the overageScore for the category so we know if it's
        #  not possible to stay under the maxScoreTarget with the options we have left.
        if isOverage:
            overageScore[category] += 1

    return wordScore


# Returns a list of the combos FROM THE SELECTION
#  i.e. ABCD contains A, B, C, D single letters, AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD pairs, etc.
def getWordCombos(word):
    combos = [0]*comboSize
    for category in range(1, comboSize):
        combos[category] = list(itertools.combinations(word, category))
        # Shuffling to ensure we're testing new things each time
        random.shuffle(combos[category])
    return combos


# Creates a list of dict objects, indexed by the number of letters. Each dict is indexed
#  by the combination of letters.
def makeCounts():
    counters = [dict()] * comboSize
    for category in range(1, comboSize):
        counters[category] = dict()
        for combo in list(itertools.combinations(allOptions, category)):
            index = "".join(combo)
            # Initialize all counters to 0
            counters[category][index] = 0
    return counters


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("--------- Beginning...")
    selectCombos()
    exit(0)
```

The output from running the script to get a subset size of 14, looks like this:

```
--------- Beginning...
SELECTIONS
ABCF
ABDH
ABEG
ACDG
ACEH
ADEF
AFGH
BCDE
BCGH
BDFG
BEFH
CDFH
CEFG
DEGH
----
----
A 7
B 7
C 7
D 7
E 7
F 7
G 7
H 7
----
AB 3
AC 3
AD 3
AE 3
AF 3
AG 3
AH 3
BC 3
BD 3
BE 3
BF 3
BG 3
BH 3
CD 3
CE 3
CF 3
CG 3
CH 3
DE 3
DF 3
DG 3
DH 3
EF 3
EG 3
EH 3
FG 3
FH 3
GH 3
----
ABC 1
ABD 1
ABE 1
ABF 1
ABG 1
ABH 1
ACD 1
ACE 1
ACF 1
ACG 1
ACH 1
ADE 1
ADF 1
ADG 1
ADH 1
AEF 1
AEG 1
AEH 1
AFG 1
AFH 1
AGH 1
BCD 1
BCE 1
BCF 1
BCG 1
BCH 1
BDE 1
BDF 1
BDG 1
BDH 1
BEF 1
BEG 1
BEH 1
BFG 1
BFH 1
BGH 1
CDE 1
CDF 1
CDG 1
CDH 1
CEF 1
CEG 1
CEH 1
CFG 1
CFH 1
CGH 1
DEF 1
DEG 1
DEH 1
DFG 1
DFH 1
DGH 1
EFG 1
EFH 1
EGH 1
FGH 1
```

I hope this helps someone else solve this type of problem!

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the dealer to shuffle the deck.

The python standard library has a module, named random, containing a shuffle function. Present your eight options, shuffle them, and return the first four or however many you need. It will be random, obeying the distribution that you desire.

EDIT

I'm not sure how I could have expressed "shuffle" more clearly
but I will try, in math, in English and in code.

Draw a random permutation of 8 distinct elements and select the first 4.

Take a shuffled deck of 8 distinct cards, deal 4 of them, discard the rest.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from pprint import pp
import random

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import typer


class Options:
    def __init__(self, all_options, k=4):
        self.all_options = all_options
        self.k = k

    def new_deck(self):
        deck = self.all_options.copy()
        random.shuffle(deck)
        return deck

    def choose_options(self):
        return self.new_deck()[: self.k]

    def choose_many_options(self, n):
        for _ in range(n):
            yield "".join(self.choose_options())


def main(n: int = 10_000_000):
    opt = Options(list("ABCDEFGH"))
    demo = list(opt.choose_many_options(3))
    pp(demo, width=22)

    df = pd.DataFrame(opt.choose_many_options(n), columns=["opt"])
    df["cnt"] = 1
    with pd.option_context("display.min_rows", 16):
        print(df.groupby("opt").sum())
    cnts = df.groupby("opt").sum().cnt.tolist()
    plt.plot(range(len(cnts)), cnts)
    plt.gca().set_xlim((0, 1700))
    plt.gca().set_ylim((0, None))
    plt.gca().set_xlabel("combination of options")
    plt.gca().set_ylabel("number of occurrences")
    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    typer.run(main)
```

output:

```
['FABE',
 'GEDC',
 'FBAC']
       cnt
opt       
ABCD  6041
ABCE  5851
ABCF  6111
ABCG  5917
ABCH  6050
ABDC  5885
ABDE  5935
ABDF  5937
...    ...
HGEC  5796
HGED  5922
HGEF  5859
HGFA  5936
HGFB  5880
HGFC  5869
HGFD  5942
HGFE  6049

[1680 rows x 1 columns]
```

[P(n, k)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n)
= P(8, 4) = n! / (n - k)!

= 40,320 / 24

= 1680

All possible combinations of options have been randomly drawn.

[image: number of occurrences of each distinct draw]

Here is the number of occurrences of each distinct draw.
Note that 5952 occurrences × 1680 gets us to ~ 10 million.
The PRNG arranged matters
"such that every option is used the same amount of times, or close to it."
Having repeatedly rolled a many-sided dice,
we see the anticipated mean and standard deviation
show up in the experimental results.

Comment: So are you saying the random function isn't actually random? If I need a subset of 2 options, I would expect to get ABCD and EFGH. Whats to say the random function wouldn't return ABCD and ABCE which means FGH were never used and ABC were used twice together? I need something that does its best to end up with a subset of evenly distributed combinations.

Comment: The  [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) module uses a [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) seeded from the [DRNG's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDRAND) high quality entropy, but that's not what you're discussing. I don't understand "saying the random function isn't actually random?" Did I say that recently?

Comment: I have yet to code this up and try it. My point is that I want the algorithm to intentionally choose a subset of N items that are evenly distributed. My gut tells me that a random function won't provide that functionality, otherwise, it wouldn't be random since it would be predictable. I would be able to say I know that if I ask for N items from this random function, I'll get these results.

Comment: I get the sense that when you use the word "random", and when I use it, in a computing context, that we are describing two distinct concepts. And here I'm not quibbling about the rate at which high quality (DRNG) entropy is stirred into the state of a PRNG. In a computing context we usually phrase this in terms of a game, where Eve wins if she can predict a bit with better than 50-50 odds. We assume Eve cannot observe the seeding. Within such a framework, the above implementation offers no advantage to such an attacker. It is "random".

Comment: Thanks for your input. My original post specifically asked for something intentional, not random though. I'll keep your ideas in mind and do some testing. If I can ask for a subset of 2 combos and it always provides ABCD and EFGH from the 70 options using the random function, then it would perform as I needed.

Comment: Oohh. I had _no idea_ what you meant by the word [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution) in "_taking a subset intentionally to get an even distribution_". Your recent remark suggests you find the usual predictable variation unacceptable to your (unspecified) use case. For example, 6050 ABCH's might be "heavy", might be drawn more often than the mean number of times. If you want 5952 ABCH's, just take their indexes, permute them, and discard the first 98 occurrences you encounter. We call this [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling).